# TypeScript Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Something' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I have been stuck with this typescript error for the past days.

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<TResult1 = ApiResponse, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: ApiResponse) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>) | (<TResult1 = void, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((va...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Code:

```
const getDetailsPromise = myCode
              ? storeApi.getDetails(params, [myCode])
              : Promise.resolve();
return getDetailsPromise.then(
              (result: ApiResponse | void) => {
                .......Some logic
                .......Some logic
                return Promise.resolve<
                  [MethodResponse, ResponseHeaders]
                >([ShippingResponse, response.headers]);
              }
            );
```

storeApi.js

```
getDetails(
        requestParams: RequestParams,
        myCode: string[]
    ): Promise<ApiResponse> { 
        .......Some logic
        .......Some logic
    }
```

Here getDetailsPromise returns either Promise or Promise. Also we are expecting myCode type as string if value exists. I am getting the above mentioned error while trying to build the application. Can somebody help/guide me to fix this issue? Any help would be really appreciated.

Playground Link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEEAOIBKUDOmA9mPmgN7CrWpgIC2UAXKvhDOAObAC+wwSEm1ScoEACJiEIADb5UAXlQAKQQBNmrdlwDaAXQCUTAAowi9EGQA8WXAWKkoAPkUvKNVDDEBXGGFSm5pZQAHRe+EQyAG5Qyu4eNHSMLADkAFIIANZQKQA0VAnU6prFBdQ8BrwA3PyCpBCo9ACeAMJEGoqoKQCMAAy93Sk1BXXCohJSsviBFmSdzW0aZYUJAPwiYpIQ0nLKOgvtUIbLKzQsM8FhBJExygbDow0AFlAyMkSdd66o8dReEL5-OMtjtpmZZqEIC8wMoTqcVOFvDIICxbHhCEI0AAfVBRIggNQGb6-eEef6AgLgy7hG6xRHI+5w058UnURl8YAvN5EO7DYBAA

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you need to indicate a proper generic type in `: Promise.resolve()`

Comment: @Anatoly Could you please explain a bit on this? Here getDetailsPromise returns either Promise<ApiResponse> | Promise<void>

Comment: Oh, wait. Can you create a minimal reproducible example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/Q

Comment: @Anatoly please find the playground link here. Also please note that typescript version we are using is bit older one v3.0.1. But still we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Anatoly Playground Link tinyurl.com/errortypescript

Comment: Look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEEAOIBKUDOmA9mPmgN7CrWpgIC2UAXKvhDOAObAC+wwSEm1ScoEACJiEIADb5UAXlQAKQQBNmrdlwDaAXQCUTAAowi9EGQA8WXAWKkoAPkUvKNVDDEBXGGFSm5pZQAHRe+EQyAG5Qyu4eNHSMLADkAFIIANZQKQA0VAnU6prFBdQ8BrwA3PyCpBCo9ACeAMJEGoqoKQCMAAy93Sk1AkINohJSsvgA6jAImJiwncpGAWYW1rZ4hEJoAD6oUUQgai4KbgUgcCrNbRoGqPHUXhC+-uOSENJyyjq37VBDAU+AUXm81kEyGECJEYisaiC6sIPpM5IENmglCivlNZvNFjB4bVRqgABZQGQyIjLB7nR5lTw+PwiMSfb74dHBEIQclgZQMwoeZThbwyCAsLb2XaoA5HE60i6CpWM17MzlQ8Kw2IisUGGrKhJ8A3UPW8fjkylEIn8IA

Comment: @Anatoly Could you please explain a bit on the changes?

Comment: I suppose TS cannot infer that the common Promise part from a union type so that's why I changed a return type in a wrapper as a Promise with a union type instead of a union of Promise-d types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Anatoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376618/anatoly). I changed the return type in a wrapper as a Promise with a union type instead of a union of Promise-d types.

Working Playground Link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEEAOIBKUDOmA9mPmgN7CrWpgIC2UAXKvhDOAObAC+wwSEm1ScoEACJiEIADb5UAXlQAKQQBNmrdlwDaAXQCUTAAowi9EGQA8WXAWKkoAPkUvKNVDDEBXGGFSm5pZQAHRe+EQyAG5Qyu4eNHSMLADkAFIIANZQKQA0VAnU6prFBdQ8BrwA3PyCpBCo9ACeAMJEGoqoKQCMAAy93Sk1AkINohJSsvgA6jAImJiwncpGAWYW1rZ4hEJoAD6oUUQgai4KbgUgcCrNbRoGqPHUXhC+-uOSENJyyjq37VBDAU+AUXm81kEyGECJEYisaiC6sIPpM5IENmglCivlNZvNFjB4bVRqgABZQGQyIjLB7nR5lTw+PwiMSfb74dHBEIQclgZQMwoeZThbwyCAsLb2XaoA5HE60i6CpWM17MzlQ8Kw2IisUGGrKhJ8A3UPW8fjkylEIn8IA